# How do I print certain parts of my 2D array in a certain order?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, printing

My function needs to take two arguments, called data, player. Argument data is a 2D string array containing the data of the [nba.txt](http://vlm1.uta.edu/~athitsos/courses/cse1310_fall2015/assignments/assignment10/nba.txt) spreadsheet. Argument player is a string.
The function finds all rows in data for which column 0 (in its lower-case version) contains as a substring the string stored in player (also in its lower-case version). For all such rows, it prints the statistics of the corresponding player.

My Code:

```
 public static void print_player_info(String[][] data, String player)
  {
   String name = player.toLowerCase();
   for(int i = 0; i<data[0].length; i++)
   {
    String namecolumn = data[i][0];
    String rownames = data[0][i];
    for(int j = 0; j<data[0].length; j++)
    {
        String temp = Arrays.toString(data[j]);
        if(temp.toLowerCase().contains(player))
        {
            System.out.println(rownames+": "+data[j][i]);
        }
    }
   }  
  }
```

It works in the desired way if I the input only retrieves one person at a time.

Example: input: "lebro"
output:

```
player: LeBron James
games played: 69
minutes per game: 36.1
etc...
```

if my input happens to retrieve more than one person it prints it stacked:input "jam"

```
player: James Harden
player: LeBron James
games played: 81
games played: 69
etc...
```

when I input "jor" it should find multiple names containing "jor" but it outputs nothing. I want to know how to fix this issue along with the previous input to be:

```
player: James Harden
games played: 81
etc...
player: LeBron James
games played: 69
etc...
```

Comment: Is the way your array is filled like this: [["James Harden", "81"], ["Lebron James", "69"]]? because that is how the 2D array should work. the second output you show does look like it is different

Comment: part of 2 lines:
James Harden, 81, 36.8...
LeBron James, 69, 36.1...

Comment: Maybe you could extend your examply with a sample of an initialized array which you pass as `String[][] data` to your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void print_player_info(String[][] data, String player){
    // lower case the search string
    String searchString = player.toLowerCase();
    // check every row in the data table except the first
    // because it has the column names in it.
    for(int row = 1; row < data.length; row++){
        // get the player name in this row
        String playerInThisRow = data[row][0];
        // lower case it and check if it contains the search string
        if(playerInThisRow.toLowerCase().contains(searchString)){
            // go throu every column in this row
            for(int column = 0; column < data[0].length; column++){
                // and get the column name and the content
                String columnContent = data[row][column];
                String columnName = data[0][column];        
                // and print it
                System.out.println(columnName +": " + columnContent);
            }  
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is always filled in exactly the same way. Like so

```
[["James Harden", "81", ...],["Lebron James", "69"]]
```

Then you always know that `array[x][0]` is the name of the player.
If the content of your array looks different than this you are using 2D arrays wrong.

Knowing that you can check if that player is what you seek and then you print his stats.

```
public static void print_player_info(String[][] data, String player)
{
    String name = player.toLowerCase();
    for(int i = 0; i<data[0].length; i++)
    {
        String namecolumn = data[i][0];
        String rownames = data[0][i];
        if(data[i][0].contains(player)){
            for(int j = 0; j<data[0].length; j++)
            {
             System.out.println(rownames+": "+data[j][i]);  
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

If it is not sure on what position the name of the player will be then it will probably be best if you first loop through the array searching for the name instead of sticking it all together. Sticking it together will make it unreliable because it might be that other data also contains the player string.

If you want to make it easier for yourself you could also take a look at Dictionaries. With this you have a object with a key and a value. Having a list of these dictionaries and a list as value you can easily search for the players you need, if their name is unique that is.

Comment: this stopped anything from printing.

Comment: nba.txt is converted into a 2d array using

`public static String[][] read_spreadsheet(String filename)
  {
    ArrayList<String> lines = read_file(filename);
    
    int rows = lines.size();
    String[][] result = new String[rows][]; 
            
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
      String line = lines.get(i);
      String [] values = line.split(",");
      result[i] = values;
    }
    return result;
  }   `